# How to make one row editable in gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I am using asp.net gridview. I don't want to add a button for switch to editmode. I just want to make one column editable in gridview on page_load.

I have a asp.net textbox on second column for **product quantity and i would like to change the value**.

As default it opens `<ItemTemplate>` and it's non-editable.

**My Gridview Columns:**

```
Product Name, Quantity, Price
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Repeater instead of a GridView.

Just build the table in the aspx page, use as Literal Control for non editable columns and a Textbox for the editable.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center">
         <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>' />  
      </td>
      <td>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPrice" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
   </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I use a ImageButton placed in a table column which clicked will save that record to database.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnEdit" ImageUrl="/images/save.jpg" CommandArgument='<%#"Edit_" + Eval("ProductID") %>' runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ClientIDMode="AutoID" CausesValidation="False" />
```

Works well for me.
Hope this helps.